# Logic Mistake in Mathematical Logic by Tourlakis

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In Tourlakis' Mathematical Logic, he claims that $\models A $ if and only if $\emptyset \models A$. This question is on page 36. The first statement implies the second is correct but the converse is incorrect.

A counterexample would be any contradiction say $A \land \neg A$.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: What's the definition of $\vDash A$ given in the book? I'm only familiar with the symbol as a relation.

Comment: 1st Def) If for every state $A$ is true then $\models A$($A$ is a tautology). 2nd Def) If the state is true for every element in $\Gamma$ then $A$ is also true($\Gamma$ tautologically implies $A$).

Comment: I don't understand the first definition you wrote. Can you reword it? To me, $\models A$ is simply an abbreviation of $\varnothing \models A$, so they mean the same by definition.

Comment: 1st Def) If for every assignment of variables $A$ is true then $\models A$. State here means an assignment of variables(Boolean ones since this is propositional logic).

Comment: Your counter example doesn't work. Let $\varphi$ be a contradiction. By definition $\varnothing\models \varphi$ means that for **every [valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic))** $v$, it holds that $\forall \psi\in \varnothing\left(v(\psi)=T\right)\implies v(\varphi)=T$. The antecedent holds vacuously, but the consequent doesn't.

Comment: See the post [Problems with using validity symbol ⊨ “vacuously”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309316/problems-with-using-validity-symbol-%e2%8a%a8-vacuously-as-in-x-%e2%8a%a8-and-%e2%8a%a8-a) as well as the post [The logical consequence of an empty set of premises](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839569/the-logical-consequence-of-an-empty-set-of-premises).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I see your error. I'm not quite sure what you mean by state, but let me try to informally translate the definitions you gave to symbols.

$\models A$ means that 
$$\forall_{states} A,$$
whereas $\Gamma\models A$ for a collection of statements $\Gamma$ means
$$\forall_{states}\left(\left(\forall_{\psi\in\Gamma}\psi\right)\implies A\right).$$

Note the careful parentheses in this second definition, since I'm fairly sure the error is one of misinterpreting the grouping of the quantifiers and symbols here. If I now put $\Gamma=\varnothing$, then I have $\forall_{\psi\in\Gamma}\psi$ becomes vacuously true, or in other words
$$\varnothing\models A$$
means that
$$\forall_{states} \mathrm{True}\implies A,$$
or 
$$\forall_{states} A,$$
since $$\mathrm{True}\implies A\text{ if and only if }A.$$

Comment: I believe "state" in the comment was meant to be "statement."

Comment: @FabioSomenzi That was my first thought as well, but "If for every statement $A$ is true" doesn't make very much sense either.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi - a "state" is a truth assignment; see page 26 : "**Def 1.3.2**. A state $v$ is a function that assigns the value $\text f$ or $\text t$ to each Boolean variable, while it assigns necessarily the value $\text f$ to the constant $\bot$ and necessarily the value $\text t$ to the constant $\top$."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Duly noted.  Thanks!